# How safe is this code

Tags: python, encryption

How safe is this code? Can the text/file be decrypted without password?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import hashlib
import base64
import os
import struct


BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS).encode()
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]

class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key, salt):
        self.key = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', key.encode(), salt.encode(), 100000)

def encrypt(self, plaintext):
    plaintext = pad(plaintext.encode())
    iv = Random.new().read(BS)
    cipher = AES.new(key=self.key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    enc = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + enc).decode()

def decrypt(self, enc):
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:BS]
    enc = enc[BS:]
    cipher = AES.new(key=self.key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(enc)
    return unpad(plaintext).decode()

def encrypt_file(self, in_file_name, out_file_name=None, chunk_size=1024 * 64):
    if not out_file_name:
        out_file_name = in_file_name + '.enc'

    iv = Random.new().read(BS)
    cipher = AES.new(key=self.key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
    file_size = os.path.getsize(in_file_name)

    with open(in_file_name, 'rb') as in_file:
        with open(out_file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
            out_file.write(struct.pack('<Q', file_size))
            out_file.write(iv)

            while True:
                chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)

                out_file.write(cipher.encrypt(chunk))

def decrypt_file(self, in_file_name, out_file_name=None, chunk_size=1024 * 64):
    if not out_file_name:
        out_file_name = os.path.splitext(in_file_name)[0]
        if out_file_name == in_file_name:
            out_file_name += '.decrypted'

    with open(in_file_name, 'rb') as in_file:
        with open(out_file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
            orig_size = struct.unpack('<Q', in_file.read(struct.calcsize('Q')))[0]
            iv = in_file.read(16)
            cipher = AES.new(key=self.key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)

            while True:
                chunk = in_file.read(chunk_size)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break

                out_file.write(cipher.decrypt(chunk))
            out_file.truncate(orig_size)
```

Can I use this script to encrypt my data? I use hashlib to derivate key, maybe I should use key derivation function from pyCrypto?

Comment: sha256 is more easily cracked by GPU than bcrypt

Comment: You should use https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/.

Comment: What @Ryan probably means is that this code is not fully secure, because you cannot detect (malicious) manipulation of ciphertexts. You would need to authenticate ciphertexts for that which fernet provides, but your code doesn't

Comment: @frozen This is not just SHA-256. It's PBKDF2 with 100 000 iterations which simply uses SHA-256. This might be enough of a slowness factor. No need for bcrypt.

Comment: What hash function uses pyCrypto PBKDF2? It doesn't have parameter `hash function` like hashlib PBKDF.

Comment: @ArtjomB., по нику вы русский, поэтому зачем усложнять жизнь. Но, почему не реализована? В документации есть, сам только что попробовал, функция есть такая, `Crypto.Protocol.KDF.PBKDF2`

Comment: Seriously, don't do ad-hoc crypto. fernet or libsodium have this all done for you.

Comment: There might be a padding oracle attack on this.

Comment: @KennyOstrom, how can I protect against padding oracle attack?

Comment: To protect against ciphertext modification, **use fernet**.

Comment: @Ranx Authenticate your ciphertext.  Use an HMAC.

Comment: I myself use Argon2 as KDF and AES-256-GCM which provides really good protection against hashing attacks and provides an authentication token built in with the encryption. And libsodium does it all for you.

Comment: Anyone doing their own encryption protocol is almost guaranteed to screw up some minor detail that makes it (relatively) easy to break. And the kind of costly and time consuming analysis and review to avoid that is done on published open source systems. Although that is relative to "nearly impossible" so anywhere in that range from trivial to almost nearly impossible..